# char conversion error when trying to use strcmp

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strcmp

I have a function which cuts a string and stores it to a new array,

```
char splitStr(int cutPoint){
    int i=0;
    char newStr[20]="";
    for(i=0;i<cutPoint;i++){
        newStr[i]=comm[i];
    }
    cout<<newStr;
}
```

The array `comm[20]` is a global array. I split the string stored in this array and compare it with an other string using `strcmp()`. This is how I does it,

```
if(strcmp(splitStr(5),"print")==0){
        cout<<"yes";
}
```

But when I does this checking, I get an error as follows,

```
C:\Users\U\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

How can I resolve this? What is the cause for this?

Comment: `char` and `const char*` are quite different types.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems, which will turn into four:

1. The first problem and the error you ask about is that you declare the function to return a *single `char`*. Not a pointer to a `char`, like a string. Change to return `char*`.
2. You declare that the function `splitStr` should return a `char` (or `char*` once you fix the first problem), but you don't actually return anything. That will lead to *undefined behavior*.
3. You never terminate the string in `newStr`. That means all C string functions you pass the string to will go out of bounds and again you'll have *undefined behavior*.
4. The fourth problem, once you fix the three above, is that you will return a pointer to the local array `newStr`. That local array will go out of scope once the function returns, leaving you with a pointer to data that no longer exists.

The two three problems are easy to solve. The fourth problem is harder. There are four common solutions to that fourth problem:

1. Make the array `static`. That means its lifetime will be the whole program, and a pointer to data in the array will never become invalid. Unfortunately that will also make the function non-reentrant, so it can never be used in threads or called for different objects.
2. Dynamically allocate the string and return the pointer returned by `new[]` (or a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which is preferred for instead of raw pointers). The problem here is that when used as you show, then you will have a memory leak (which will be solved if you use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).
3. Pass the string array into the function as an argument. Return that string.
4. And the best solution when dealing with strings in C++: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)!

And if you use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) then you should use its [substring function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) instead of making up your own.